# What does cursor function of RWDBCursor do?

Tags: sql, rogue-wave

```
RWDBSelector select1 = myDB.database().selector();
RWDBCursor cursor1 = select1.cursor();
```

What does the last line mean?
What does `.cursor()` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RWDBSelector::cursor()`](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/sourcepro/docs/12.5/html/sourceproref/classRWDBSelector.html#a67e5fd8e4f50903740e78fe466be173b) gives you a cursor for the execution of your RWDBSelector.

For more information about how to work with DB cursors see either this excellent example for [`RWDBCursor`](http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/sourcepro/docs/12.5/html/sourceproref/classRWDBCursor.html#example) or the documentation for your specific database.

Comment: -thnks a lot.this helped.